# (/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL) Trying to build a GLFW application in docker

Tags: c++, linux, docker, gcc, opengl

thank you for taking the time to read this question and hopefully helping.

So I am trying to use docker to build a GLFW application and I can't get ld to link in my OpenGL so file. I've installed many different packages that should include libGL.so, and it is present at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. It's a symlink to libGL.1.so, which is a symlink to libGL.1.7.0 which appears to be an actual shared object.

```
g++ --static -o bin/x86-64/linux/main build/x86-64/linux/main.o --libs=glfw3 -lm -lGLU -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGL
```

That's the command in my makefile that causes ld to return code 1. I've made sure to use capital GL in the command, I've made sure that ld is looking in the right directory, and i can verify that libGL.so is present.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:24; build_x86-64_linux] Error 1
```

I'm racking my brain trying to follow every single stackoverflow, askubuntu and nvidia forum entry where someone has the same error but all of their problems seem to be solved by fixing broken symlinks or installing a missing dependency.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libglu1-mesa
RUN apt-get install -y libglu1-mesa-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libglm-dev
RUN apt-get install -y mingw-w64
RUN apt-get install -y libglfw3
RUN apt-get install -y vulkan-tools
RUN apt-get install -y libvulkan-dev
RUN apt-get install -y vulkan-validationlayers-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y spirv-tools
RUN apt-get install -y mesa-common-dev
RUN apt-get install -y mesa-utils 
RUN apt-get install -y freeglut3-dev

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata

RUN apt-get install -y libglfw3-dev

ARG CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

VOLUME /root/env
WORKDIR /root/env
```

That is my Dockerfile, and as you can see there I have all the necessary dependencies.

[The result of ls -ls at /usr/lib/x86_54-linux-gnu/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyuzK.png)

You can see there that my shared object file is present and as and where I described it and told the linker to look.

If there is anything else I should include please tell me what I should add and ill update the post with the relevant information.

Comment: If you're building a `--static` binary, then you need the corresponding static library `libGL.a`.  (I'm not sure why `ls -l` would write out a PNG file like you show here, though; I'd expect it to produce text that you could include directly in the question.)

Comment: How would I link in libGL.a, and why didn't I need to link to static libraries for anything else? 

Also, sorry about the PNG, I was very tired and not thinking clearly when I made this question.

Comment: There is no `libGL.a` in a meaningful way. That file is part of the GL implementation, so the graphics driver, and statically linking that is not going to get you anywhere (and completely outside the few ABI guarantees OpenGL on Linux/Unix is making at all).

Comment: So what you're saying is i should stop trying to statically linking my application? is that going to allow it to see libGL.so?

Comment: Yes, just remove the "--static" and it will work.